# Expression pattern of type 'String' cannot match values of type 'AnyObject'

Tags: swift

```
init?(plistRepresentation : AnyObject){
            switch plistRepresentation{
            case "viewing":
                self = .viewing
    }
}
```

The above code generates "Expression pattern of type 'String' cannot match values of type 'AnyObject'" error. But the moment I add "as Sttring"

```
init?(plistRepresentation : AnyObject){
                switch plistRepresentation{
                case "viewing" as String:
                    self = .viewing
        }
    }
```

the error goes away.. Can anyone explains to me how this works? It looks kinda confusing to me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`AnyObject` is a generalise type that includes all type of object type like array, dictionary, set, string, etc.

> **AnyObject** refers to any instance of a class, and is equivalent to id in Objective-C. It's useful when you specifically want to work with a reference type, because it won't allow any of Swift's structs or enums to be used.

Swift's switch want a specific type to match the case that's the reason when you put `as String` the error goes away.

More detail on AnyObject can be found [here](https://medium.com/@mimicatcodes/any-vs-anyobject-in-swift-3-b1a8d3a02e00)

Comment: I am more curious of the switch statement. I read the article you have given. So switch case always need a concrete time? But isn;t compile aware of the fact that I am using a String type? Because the error already states so?

Comment: @progammingBeignner since you are pattern matching on an object of type `AnyObject`, you cannot simply try pattern matching literal values of a class conforming to `AnyObject`. You need to explicitly cast to the concrete type (`String` in your case) to let the compiler know that before pattern matching the value, it should pattern match the type casting as well.

Comment: @DávidPásztor ok, that sounds reasonable to me. Thanks!